# How to setup my UserService using the cake pattern inside of play?

Tags: scala, playframework, cake-pattern

Currently I am using guice to wireup my UserService inside of a controller like:

```
@Singleton
class UserController @Inject()(userService: UserService) extends Controller {
  def show(userId: Int) {
      val user = userService.get(userId)
      Ok("hello " + user.name)
  }
}
```

My UserService looks like:

```
abstract class UserService {
  def get(userId: Int): User
}

class UserServiceImpl @Inject()(val userDao: UserDao) extends UserService {
  def get(userId: Int): User = {
    // ....
  }
}
```

**If I wanted to drop guice as a dependency and use the cake pattern, what would the code look like and how would I integrate this into Play so I could use this service in my Controllers?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion with package names to give you an idea of how to organize all of this.

```
 package controllers.users

 trait UserController extends Controller {
     this: UserService =>

     def show(userId: Int) = {
         val user = this.get(userId)
         Ok("hello "  + user.name)
     }
 }

 package services.users

 trait UserService {
     def get(userId: Int): User
 }

 package services.users.impl

 trait UserServiceImpl extends UserService {
     def get(userId: Int) = { /*implementation*/ }
 }

 package controllers

 object UserController extends UserController with UserServiceImpl
```

You can put your services and your controller `trait`s anywhere you like in the project. You should put your controller `object` directly in the `controllers` package to make routing most convenient.

Comment: what is the name of this syntax/concept:  ```this: UserService =>```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, there is no link between UserService trait and UserServiceImpl trait, am I right?

Comment: The name of this construct is the 'self type'. You're right, the Impl should of course extend the interface (I've edited my answer).